# Running Python Script from PowerShell Syntax Error

Tags: python, windows, powershell

Following is a summary of the problem along with relevant info about OS, System Environment Variables.

Upon starting PowerShell,  screen shows

```
Windows Powershell  
Copyright © 2009 Microsoft Corporation  
PS C:\Users>
```

My Input is:

```
Python
```

Output is:

```
Python 2.7.4 default Apr 8 2013 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32"  
Type “help” ……etc.
```

My next input is:

```
Python CleanupStops.py
```

Output is:

```
File <stdin>,line 1  
Python CleanupStops.py  
              ^ "  
Syntax Error: invalid syntax"
```

The script resides in the directory pyscripts which is set in the System Environment Variables as shown below.

```
C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts\pyscripts;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages;
```

Note that my OS is 64-bit SPI while Python 2.7.4 is 32 bit Intel.

Operating System:

- Windows 7 Professional 64-bit SP1
  Installation Date: 4/3/2015 10:13:51 PM

.NET Frameworks installed:

- v4.5 Full
- v4.5 Client
- v3.5 SP1
- v3.0 SP2
- v2.0 SP2

Comment: You are already in python so trying to run python again doesn't work. I don't know powershell and microsurf likely made it completely incomprehensible but how about instead of `Python` as the first powershell command, try `python CleanupStops.py` or even just `CleanupStops.py` as your Windows will likely be configured to associate .py files with python.

Comment: Just directly call `python CleanupStops.py` as advised above. *microsurf likely made it completely incomprehensible* ? PowerShell is quite comprehensible, don't say things like this.

Answer (score 4):

Your first `Python` statement started the Python interpreter in interactive mode. If you want to run a Python script from there you need something like this (assuming that the file is in the current directory):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('.\\CleanupStops.py')
```

Type `exit()` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to quit the interactive interpreter.

A statement `python CleanupStops.py` is used when you want to run a Python script directly from PowerShell or CMD:

```
PS C:\> python C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts\pyscripts\CleanupStops.py
```

or

```
PS C:\> Set-Location C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts\pyscripts
PS C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts\pyscripts> python CleanupStops.py
```

If you associated `.py` files with the Python interpreter during installation you should even be able to run Python scripts directly (without explicitly specifying the interpreter), as @tdelaney pointed out in the comments to your question:

```
PS C:\> CleanupStops.py
```

Note, however, that the latter (calling the script without interpreter and path) will only work if the directory containing the script is listed in the `$env:Path` environment variable (and the extension `.py` is listed in the `$env:PATHEXT` variable, as @eryksun pointed out in the comments). If the directory is not listed in `$env:Path` you need to call the script with its absolute or relative path.

```
PS C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts\pyscripts> .\CleanupStops.py
```

If the installer did not prepare the environment properly you can easily do it yourself. Just run the following 4 statements from an elevated PowerShell prompt:

```
[environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path', "$env:Path;C:\python27", 'Machine')
[environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATHEXT', "$env:PATHEXT;.py", 'Machine')
cmd /c 'assoc .py=Python.File'
cmd /c 'ftype Python.File="C:\python27\python.exe" "%1" %*'
```

The new settings become effective the next time you start PowerShell (or CMD).